# MySQL Datetime range not working

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, where-clause, between

I want to search for rows where the datetime posted is less than a certain value and more than another.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE ip_address = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' AND 'date' >'2014-12-16 15:59:48' AND 'date' < '2014-12-16 16:29:48'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE ip_address = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' AND 'date' BETWEEN '2014-12-16 15:59:48' AND  '2014-12-16 16:29:48'
```

Both of these queries return 0 rows when I can confirm I have about 20 rows.

Could somebody help?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: See why it's a bad idea to use reserved words to name your columns? Right now you're comparing the string literal `'date'` with other string literals representing date values. Try enclosing `DATE` (note upper case) in backticks instead.

Comment: (I'm obviously assuming the IP address is not literally `xxx.etc.`, and you just obfuscated it?)

Comment: You are right mustaccio, and yeah, I use real IPs that are stored as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'date' is a string literal, whereas, if you have named your field date then you need to use backticks, e.g. `date`

What you are doing is comparing the value of "date" (a string literal) with a date. You want to compare the value of the field named date with a date, so you need to use backticks instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eilidh! You have nailed it. Can't believe I didn't think of that! Will accept as answer soon.

Comment: I have a column called dat that contains Y-m-d H:i:s and I want to get all rows that are within the range of two dates. Your answer worked :)

Comment: No problem at all :) As mustaccio pointed out in his comment, it is a bad idea to name columns with reserved words because you need the backticks and if you forget them it will cause an error. It's a bad habit to get into (but one I admit I still do as well!)

Comment: I usually name the column datetime as well, don't know why I changed hehe! Thanks again